# Explode a string into array with Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

Is there any function for splitting a string into chunks based on a separator? The opposite of `join` filter.

I mean something like `explode` in PHP. I need to check if `class` parameter contains a given string:

```
{% macro nav_item(route, label, class, tooltip, placement) %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if 'icon-white' in class|explode(' ') %}
    {% edif %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution for twig prior to 1.10.3

<del>AFAIK, there is no such filter in twig.</del> However you might use `in` operator as following:

```
{% spaceless %}
    {% set test_class = ' ' ~ class ~ ' ' %}
    {% if ' icon-white ' in test_class %}
    {% endif %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

So, for example, if your class looks like `'some-class icon-white icon-white-2'` then test_class will take value of `' some-class icon-white icon-white-2 '` and `in` will return `true` for this class. It will, however, return `false` for `' some-class icon-white-2 '`, as expected.

Comment: lol why downvote? because `split` was introduced into twig 7 months AFTER my answer???

Comment: I assume you answered right some time ago, but your answer is not useful today.

Answer (score 25):

As of Twig 1.10.3 there is the [split](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html)  filter.

```
{% set classes = class|split(' ') %}
```